# Zip up all Paperclip attachments stored on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, amazon-s3, paperclip

Paperclip is a great upload plugin for Rails. Storing uploads on the local filesystem or Amazon S3 seems to work well. I'd just assume store files on the localhost, but the use of S3 is required for this app as it will be hosted on Heroku.

How would I go about getting all of my uploads/attachments from S3 in a single zipped download?

Getting a zip of files from the *local filesystem* seems straight forward. It's getting the files from S3 that has me puzzled. I think it may have something to do with the way that rubyzip handles files referenced by URL. I've tried various approaches but can't seem to avoid errors.

```
    format.zip {
                registrations_with_attachments = Registration.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE abstract_file_name NOT LIKE ""')
                headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'  
                tmp_filename = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/tmp_zip_" <<
                                Time.now.to_f.to_s <<
                                ".zip"

                # rubyzip gem version 0.9.1
                # rdoc http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/                
                Zip::ZipFile.open(tmp_filename, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zip|
                  #get all of the attachments

                  # attempt to get files stored on S3
                  # FAIL
                  registrations_with_attachments.each { |e| zip.add("abstracts/#{e.abstract.original_filename}", e.abstract.url(:original, false)) }
                  # => No such file or directory - http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/original/abstract.txt
                  # Should note that these files in S3 bucket are publicly accessible. No ACL. 

                  # works with local storage. Thanks to Henrik Nyh
                  # registrations_with_attachments.each { |e| zip.add("abstracts/#{e.abstract.original_filename}", e.abstract.path(:original))   }
                end     

                send_data(File.open(tmp_filename, "rb+").read, :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => tmp_filename.to_s)
                File.delete tmp_filename
          }
```

Comment: Wondering if the solution here is to use the AWS-S3 gem to get all files in the bucket and not use paperclip?

Comment: You almost certainly want to use to_file() instead of url().

Comment: Yeah. I though of that too. Gives this error.

    can't convert Paperclip::Tempfile into String

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You almost certainly want to use `e.abstract.to_file.path` instead of `e.abstract.url(...)`.

See:

- [Paperclip::Storage::S3::to_file](http://dev.thoughtbot.com/paperclip/classes/Paperclip/Storage/S3.html#M000089) (should return a `TempFile`)
- [TempFile::path](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/classes/Tempfile.html#M004422)

## UPDATE

From the [changelog](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/NEWS):

> New in 3.0.1:
>
> - API CHANGE: `#to_file` has been removed. Use the [`#copy_to_local_file`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3#copy_to_local_file-instance_method) method instead.

Comment: update this answer to paperclip > 3.0 , .to_file has been removed :(

Comment: @vladr & @chaserx: Hi, I am sorry I am a little confused. This is what I currently have, and I can't seem to find what the correct destination_url argument will be for the copy_to_local_file method.

`@user_attachments.each do |e|

zip.add(e.document_file_name, e.document.copy_to_local_file(:original, "#{Rails.root}"))

end`

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@vlard's solution is ok. However I've run into some issues with the `to_file`. It creates a tempfile and the garbage collector deletes (sometimes) the file before it was added to the zip file. Therefor, I'm getting random `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`  errors.

So I'm using the following code now (I've kept the initial code variables names for consistency with the initial question)

```
format.zip {
            registrations_with_attachments = Registration.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE abstract_file_name NOT LIKE ""')
            headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'  

            #please note that using nanoseconds option in strftime reduces the risks concerning the situation where 2 or more  users initiate the download in the same time
            tmp_filename = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/tmp_zip_" <<
                            Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S-%N').to_s <<   
                            ".zip"

            # rubyzip gem version 0.9.4                
            zip = Zip::ZipFile.open(tmp_filename, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) 
            zip.close

            registrations_with_attachments.each { |e|
                 file_to_add = e.file.to_file
                 zip = Zip::ZipFile.open(tmp_filename)
                 zip.add("abstracts/#{e.abstract.original_filename}", file_to_add.path)
                 zip.close
                 puts "added #{file_to_add.path} to #{tmp_filename}"  #force garbage collector to keep the file_to_add until after the file has been added to zip
            }

            send_data(File.open(tmp_filename, "rb+").read, :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => tmp_filename.to_s)
            File.delete tmp_filename
      }
```

Comment: Can you explain why your solution forces the garbage collector to wait? Thanks!

Comment: I can't explain why it works, but can confirm that I was having the exact same issue and this fixed it!

Comment: What is the `b+` in the File.open method? I believe there is only `r(+)`,`w(+)` and `a(+)`.

Comment: @Jared, see the comment on last line of the block passed to `registrations_with_attachments.each` : the puts method uses the `file_to_add` variable, therefore the garbage collector is forced to keep the variable in memory when executing`zip.add("abstracts/#{e.abstract.original_filename}", file_to_add.path)`

Comment: @Marc `rb(+)` = `r(+)` + `b` where `b` means  `Binary file mode. Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly specified.`