# image_tag encoded in base64 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, actionmailer

Is there any way to make image_tag in rails 3.1 convert the image into base64 format to send it in the email.

If there is no way to do this can anyone tell me the way to send emails containing images which are stored server side? If i just use image_tag for rendering images they are not displayed in the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send images with emails use attachment property on mail to sent the file with mail:

```
attachments['logo.png'] = File.read(Rails.public_path + '/images/logo.png')
```

This file will be sent with mail in attachments. To use this image on email body use `attachments.inline[]` and then in template `image_tag attachments[].url`.

Also note that Rails 3 have [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2686) with inline attachments, as they present, all ordinary attachments will not be visible in major email clients, as Thunderbird or Outlook.

Comment: Does this mean that if some images are stored in the amazon w3 servers they won't be displayed in the email?

Comment: No, just in this case you should get this file to your server to attach. For example with `Paperclip` see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2391374/698718).

Comment: I'm trying to attach a file like this

`@attachments = {}
    @attachments['blank'] = File.read("#{Rails.root + '/app/assets/images/logo.png'}")`

but i get such an error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method `inline' for #<Hash:0x1051c86c>
from (pry):55:in `daily_email'`

what is wrong?

Comment: There no need to define `attachments` as this is method on `ActionMailer::Base`. Just use `attachments` without `@` and initialization.

Answer (score 2):

in the mailer you can add inline attachments that you can use in the html for the mail:
for example you have a mailer action send_mail(user)

```
 def send_mail(user)
   attachments.inline['logo.gif'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/logo.gif")
   mail( :to=>"#{user.name} #{user.last_name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Payment received")
 end
```

and then in the mail view: the file send_mail.html

```
 <center> <%= image_tag attachments['logo.gif'].url, :alt => "Our logo" -%> </center>
```