# Paperclip + S3 massive zipping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, zip, paperclip

If you got Paperclip + AWS S3 working in your rails 3 application and you want to zip attachments related to a model how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Some questions at stackoverflow are [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338758/zip-up-all-paperclip-attachments-stored-on-s3), some paperclip methods are gone.

Lets say we got a User and it `:has_many => user_attachments`

```
GC.disable
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
zip_filename = "User attachments - #{@user.id}.zip" # the file name
tmp_filename = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{zip_filename}" # the path
Zip::ZipFile.open(tmp_filename, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zip|
  @user.user_attachments.each { |e| 
    attachment = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(e.attachment) #has_attached_file :attachment (,...)
    zip.add("#{e.attachment.original_filename}", attachment.path)
  }
end
send_data(File.open(tmp_filename, "rb+").read, :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => zip_filename)
File.delete tmp_filename
GC.enable
GC.start
```

The trick is to disable the GC in order to avoid `Errno::ENOENT` exception. The GC will delete the downloaded attachment from S3 before it gets zipped.

Sources: 
[to_file broken in master?](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/833) 
[io_adapters.for(object.attachment).path failing randomly](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/986)